# How to get screen size through python curses

Tags: command-line, python, programming, ncurses

I'm writing a terminal program and need to get the size of the TTY I'm using. The Internet seems to suggest this can be done with curses, but I can't seem to find out how in python. I'm trying to avoid using the ROWS and COLUMNS environment variables if possible :)

Answer (score 12):

Apparently, the getmaxyx() method is what you need. It returns a (height, width) tuple.

[Python reference](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.window.getmaxyx)

[Some tutorial](https://www.ironalbatross.net/wiki/index.php5?title=Python_Curses#Getting_screen_dimensions)

Edit: tutorial link is dead, [here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20111114120248/http://ironalbatross.net/wiki/index.php5?title=Python_Curses#Getting_screen_dimensions) the archived version. And here's the example from that link:

> Now lets say we want to draw X's down the diagonal. We will need to
>   know when to stop, so we will need to know the width and the height of
>   the screen. This is done with the stdscr.getmaxyx() function. This
>   function returns a tuple with the (height, width) values.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import curses
import time
stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.cbreak()
curses.noecho()
stdscr.keypad(1)

try:
# Run your code here
    height,width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    num = min(height,width)
    for x in range(num):
        stdscr.addch(x,x,'X')
    stdscr.refresh()
    time.sleep(3)
finally:
    curses.nocbreak()
    stdscr.keypad(0)
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Would expect to find this on SO, but nontheless, perfect answer, thanks! Signed up just to +1 this. :)

Comment: Funny, the tutorial link is now dead.

Comment: @RandomInsano edited my answer. I think it was just some random tutorial I found through Google.